# Oracle left outer join with is null in JOIN vs WHERE condition (example)

Tags: oracle, outer-join

I cannot understand the reason why Oracle returns this strange results.
I think the code is really very clear.

I expected 
No condition = (is NOT null in OUTER JOIN cond) + (is null in OUTER JOIN cond)

Since I interpret IS NULL / IS NOT NULL in a outer join right table column as a EXISTS / NOT EXISTS condition.

Why am I wrong?

```
DESCRIPTION                          COUNT(1)
---------------------------------- ----------
No condition                             6403
is NOT null in OUTER JOIN cond           6403
is not null in where cond                6401
is null in OUTER JOIN cond               6247
is null in where cond                       2
proof flh_id_messaggio is not null          0
proof flh_stato is not null                 0


  SELECT 'is null in OUTER JOIN cond ' description, count(1)
    FROM    netatemp.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013 t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            eni_flussi_hub c ON
            c.flh_id_messaggio = t.flh_id_messaggio  
            AND c.flh_stato is null   
   WHERE 1 = 1 
       And t.flh_stato = 'PA'
         AND t.OWNER = 'ETL' 
UNION
  SELECT 'is NOT null in OUTER JOIN cond ' description, count(1)
    FROM    netatemp.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013 t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            eni_flussi_hub c ON
            c.flh_id_messaggio = t.flh_id_messaggio  
            AND c.flh_stato is not null   
   WHERE 1 = 1 
       And t.flh_stato = 'PA'
         AND t.OWNER = 'ETL'
UNION
  SELECT 'is null in where cond ' description, count(1)
    FROM    netatemp.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013 t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            eni_flussi_hub c ON
            c.flh_id_messaggio = t.flh_id_messaggio                
   WHERE 1 = 1 
       And t.flh_stato = 'PA'
         AND t.OWNER = 'ETL'
         AND c.flh_stato is null 
UNION
  SELECT 'is not null in where cond ' description, count(1)
    FROM    netatemp.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013 t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            eni_flussi_hub c ON
            c.flh_id_messaggio = t.flh_id_messaggio                
   WHERE 1 = 1 
       And t.flh_stato = 'PA'
         AND t.OWNER = 'ETL'
         AND c.flh_stato is not null 
UNION
  SELECT 'No condition' description, count(1)
    FROM    netatemp.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013 t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            eni_flussi_hub c ON
            c.flh_id_messaggio = t.flh_id_messaggio                
   WHERE 1 = 1 
       And t.flh_stato = 'PA'
         AND t.OWNER = 'ETL'
UNION select 'proof flh_stato is not null' description, count(1)
from eni_flussi_hub
where flh_stato is null         
UNION select 'proof flh_id_messaggio is not null' description, count(1)
from eni_flussi_hub
where flh_id_messaggio is null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` equivalent query is obtained by placing the `NULL` condition in the `WHERE` clause, not in the `OUTER JOIN` clause. By the way this is what we observe from your result:

```
No condition                             6403
is not null in where cond                6401
is null in where cond                       2
```

2 rows from the main tables have no corresponding ids in the joined table.

---

When you place the condition in the `OUTER JOIN` clause, you're telling Oracle to `OUTER JOIN`  your main table to a **subset of rows** from the joined table.

Since `c.flh_stato` is never null, the condition is redundant and we get the same result as the no-condition query:

```
No condition                             6403
is NOT null in OUTER JOIN cond           6403
```

With the condition `c.flh_stato IS NULL` in the join clause, we join the main table to an empty result set, thus we get one row for each row of the main table (we deduct that the main table has 6247 rows with this condition):

```
is null in OUTER JOIN cond               6247
```

Comment: Really really good to know. Even if I think oracle is strange... Why allow to prefilter tables in the JOIN condition.. it's weird.. I thougt to use in the JOIN conditions just the join condition and maybe the EXIST / NOT EXIST equivalent.. not a prefilter...

Comment: @Gik25 I'm not sure this is specific to Oracle. This seems to be a direct application of the SQL synthax. See these examples behaving similarly in [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e53/3), [MS SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64e53/2). Most often, an anti-join with `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` is easier to understand and has the same optimizer options  in Oracle (beware of nulls though).